# How should we tag questions about "The Last of Us" (TV show and video game)?

Tags: discussion, tags

How should questions about the HBO TV show *The Last of Us* (2023) and the video game it is based on, *The Last of Us* (2013) be tagged?

Should a franchise tag and a separate game / TV show tag with the year appended be used? ([the-last-of-us](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-last-of-us) + [the-last-of-us-2023](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-last-of-us-2023) for the TV show or [the-last-of-us-2013](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-last-of-us-2013) for the video game) Or should we tag in a different way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've not played the games and I haven't watched the series yet but I doubt they'll differ so drastically that they'd be considered 100% separate. We also don't have any *The Last of Us* questions yet that I can tell.

With that said just use [the-last-of-us](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-last-of-us) for both and, if you need to, distinguish with media tags. For example [the-last-of-us](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-last-of-us) [video-games](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-games) and [the-last-of-us](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-last-of-us) [tv](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv), similar to how we do with some major franchises.

Comment: "*but I doubt they'll differ so drastically that they'd be considered 100% separate*" As one who has played the games and currently watching the series, I can say that there have been enough differences so far to warrant separate tags. The series has both added and changed content

Comment: @Wondercricket In cases where the 2 differ and/or the question is about one work only that's where it would make sense to use in conjunction with the media tags.